# web-mode for .js suffixed files

Tags: web-mode, javascript

I have (somewhat) successfully installed and configured `web-mode`.

But one thing doesn't work /w (react.js) JSX: I'm doing a project that requires the files to have the suffix `'.js'` and I'm trying to override the built-in `js-mode` assigned to them. I have gotten to having `web-mode` loaded for them (mode part of modeline says `(Web ARev yas Trim)`), but tag coloring and indentation doesn't work for `.js` suffixed files, but does for `.jsx` suffixed ones.

My `web-mode` loading and configuration currently looks like this:

```
(require 'web-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.js\\'" . web-mode)) ;; Override?
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.jsx\\'" . web-mode))

(defun my-web-mode-hook ()
  "web-mode settings"
  (setq web-mode-markup-indent-offset 2)
  (setq web-mode-css-indent-offset 2)
  (setq web-mode-code-indent-offset 2))
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook  'my-web-mode-hook)
```

Anything obviously wrong? (Perhaps naively) it looks to me like the `js-mode` major mode is loaded first, and only afterwards `web-mode`, which doesn't manage to "take over" the buffer completely.

I guess I could look at the system sources and erase all configuration of `js-mode` from there, but that sounds too heavy-handed in my ears, so I'd prefer to avoid that, and I'm not even sure my theory about loading order is correct.

Emacs 24.5.1 on OS X installed via Homebrew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this

`(setq web-mode-content-types-alist
  '(("jsx"  . "/some/react/path/.*\\.js[x]?\\'")))`